# Am I guaranteed to have exactly one JavaVM per process using JNI?

Tags: java, c, jvm, java-native-interface

I have a C shared library that is used from a Java application via JNI.  I need to store some expensive-to-calculate data which will be valid for the lifespan of a `JavaVM`.  I would like to store this in a `static` variable in C, so that it gets calculated exactly once.

Of course, this will fail if it is possible for my library to be used from multiple `JavaVM`s in the same process.  My static values would only be valid in the first `JavaVM`.  If my library is being loaded from Java via `System.loadLibrary` in a `static` block on a class, is it ever possible for said library to be used across multiple JavaVMs without having to completely unload my C shared library?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. Most popular JVM implementations, in particular, HotSpot JVM and its derivatives, allow only one Java Virtual Machine per process.

In fact, an implementation allowing multiple VMs in one process, will not be compliant with the JNI specification, as the documentation to [JNI_CreateJavaVM](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/specs/jni/invocation.html#jni_createjavavm) and [JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/specs/jni/invocation.html#jni_getcreatedjavavms) explicitly says that

> Creation of multiple VMs in a single process is not supported.

Comment: Wonderful!  That's exactly what I needed.  The most poplar ones don't do it AND the spec forbids it =D

Comment: But I have difficulties with the concept of writing insufficiencies of a particular implementation into the specification. Especially defining an API for querying “all Java VMs that have been created” and then writing into its documentation that there can only be one.

Comment: @Holger Agreed.  It looks like that function may have been an anachronism from before they limited things to one JVM.  But at the very least I can say "all current implementations have one" "the spec says you can only have one" and then I can do a check (such as in JNI_OnLoad) to confirm there is only one.